# iphone SDK: Best way to select two objects (for comparison)

Tags: iphone, object, comparison

I have multiple objects, each with a series of attributes.  I'd like the user to select two objects and then the app will display a comparison of the respective object's attributes.  I'm having difficulty deciding how best to select the two objects.  I would use a UITableView, but how to select two cells before proceeding?  Alternatively, I could display UIButtons, but again, how best to select two before proceeding?  Perhaps there is another way that isnt occuring to me.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your tableView allows selections:

`myTableView.allowsSelection = YES;`

Define two properties two store the first and second selection index paths:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *firstSelection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *secondSelection;
```

Set the selection whenever the user selects a row. In this example, I use FIFO approach to the selections. In addition, if there are two selections already made, show the object attributes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                   didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // push the selections up each time. The selected items will always be the
   // last two selections
   self.firstSelection = self.secondSelection;
   self.secondSelection = indexPath;

   // if both selections are not nil, two selections have been made.
   if (self.firstSelection && self.secondSelection)
      [self showComparisonOfObject:self.firstSelection
                        withObject:self.secondSelection];
}
```

Finally, use a checkmark accessory on the selected rows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = 
                    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = someTextYouDefine;
   cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

   // this is where the magic happens
   BOOL cellSelected = indexPath == self.firstSelection || 
                       indexPath == self.secondSelection; 

   cell.accessoryType = cellSelected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark :
                                       UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

   // the following two lines ensure that the checkmark does not cause
   // the label to be off-center
   cell.indentationLevel = cellSelected ? 1 : 0;
   cell.indentationWidth = 20.0f;

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks AnswerBot.  Appreciated.

Comment: AnswerBot is happy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UITableView` and use the checkmark `accessoryView`, then have a "Proceed" button once two objects are selected.

However, if you want to ensure exactly two objects (no more) get selected, then you could use two `UIPicker`s, one above the other, so the use can select the two that way.